# multidimensional array not getting passed from function (excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

In the following function I build a 5 by 2 array.  the syntax is

[code]

```
function alpha( code)

dim ancestors(5,2)
(code)

dim result(11)
result(8) = code
result(9) = ancestors
result(10) = code

alpha = result


end function

sub 

dim ancestors5(5,2)
alpha_result = alpha( code )

ancestors5(5,2) = alpha_result(9)


end sub
```

[/code]

An even simpler code is as follows:

```
function alpha(code) as variant

dim arr(5,2)

result(1) = arr
result(2) = something_else
alpha = arr

end function

sub

dim arr2(5,2)

call = alpha(code)

arr2(5,2) = call(1)

end sub
```

temp =

As you can see from the screen shots there is definitely something in the alpha_result(9) array but it is not getting passed on to the ancestors5 array.

[image]

[image]

Comment: `dim ancestors(5,2)` actually creates a 6x3 array, since the default lbound is zero, and you're declaring the ubounds as 5 and 2.  So you get 0-5 and 0-2.  Would be useful to update your question with a compilable example of the problem: right now it's pretty hard to follow. Your `alpha` function doesn't return anything for example...

Comment: I tried declaring ancestors as ancestors(6,3) but that didn't do anything.

Comment: You need to improve your sample code so people can see what you're trying to do there.

Comment: code improved slightly.  the code your produced below doesn't seem to reflect what I'm trying to do.

Comment: See my edit.  It's still unclear what you're trying to do: what do you *expect* to happen in your code?  If you're trying to do a direct array assignment from `alpha_result(9)`, that's not how it's done in VBA

Comment: I have a (5,2) array built in a function.  The function returns 11 results.  One of the results is the (5,2) array.  I then want to assign that array to a declaration in the subroutine.  All the other assignments work, so why doesn't alpha_result(9) work?

Comment: I should also point out that I often pass single dimension arrays using this method.  But when I use the same method with multidimensional arrays it doesn't work.  Here we can make the code even simpler.

Comment: I made another edit.

Comment: I made edits to your answer.

Comment: I made edits to your answer but it appears that someone deleted them.  Thanks to whoever that was for ruining our communication.

Comment: Typically you don't edit someone else's answer, but either edit your question or add comments below the answer.  In any case, I think I understand what you want to do, and my answer covers it: I don't think I can improve it.

Comment: I understand my mistake now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
Function Alpha()
Dim a(5, 2)
Dim b(11)

    a(1, 1) = "test" 'e.g.
    b(9) = a

    Alpha = b
End Function

Sub tester()
    Dim arr, arr2  ' Variants
    Dim arr3(5, 2) ' declare empty array with dimensions 0-5, 0-2

    arr = Alpha() '>> arr is now a 1-d array with dimensions 0-11

    MsgBox arr(9)(1, 1) '>> "test" value from 2-d array stored at
                        '    arr(9)
    'or...
    arr2 = arr(9)     'arr2 is now a 2-d array with dimensions 0-5, 0-2
    MsgBox arr2(1, 1) '>> "test"

    ' it's unclear what you *want* to happen here:
    arr3(5, 2) = arr(9) '<< here you're assigning the 2-d array
                        '   stored in arr(9) to the element of
                        '   arr3() at 5,2
End Sub
```